# Is there a way to extract information from Fibaro HC2's virtual device file

Tags: automation

My Home Automation server (Fibaro Home Centre 2) died and I had to move over to HC3.  The migration, from cloud backup did not take many things over.  One such category is Virtual Devices stored in `.vfib` files.

To carry on my programming of it, I need to extract information from them.  Whats the format of the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `.vfib` file is just a json file.  A tidied example follows

```json
{
  "name": "RH Garage Door",
  "type": "virtual_device",
  "properties": {
    "deviceIcon": 1022,
    "categories": "[\"other\"]",
    "currentIcon": "1025",
    "log": "",
    "logTemp": "",
    "mainLoop": "local name   = 'Grg Door Right';\nlocal id     = fibaro:getSelfId ();\nlocal sensor = fibaro:getValue ('540', 'value');\n\nif sensor ~= '0'\nthen   \n  --fibaro:call (device, \"setProperty\", \"ui.LabelStatus.value\", \"OPEN\");\n  fibaro:call (id, 'setProperty', 'currentIcon', 1026);\n  fibaro:startScene (132,{{['add']=name..' Open'}});\nelse  \n  --fibaro:call (device, \"setProperty\", \"ui.LabelStatus.value\", \"CLOSED\");\n  fibaro:call (id, 'setProperty', 'currentIcon', 1025);\n  fibaro:startScene (132,{{['add']=name..' Closed'}});\nend",
    "visible": "true",
    "rows": [
      {
        "type": "label",
        "elements": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "lua": false,
            "waitForResponse": false,
            "caption": "Status",
            "name": "LabelStatus",
            "favourite": false,
            "main": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "elements": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "lua": true,
            "waitForResponse": false,
            "caption": "Open",
            "name": "ButtonOpen",
            "empty": false,
            "msg": "fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOn')",
            "buttonIcon": 1027,
            "favourite": false,
            "main": false
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "lua": true,
            "waitForResponse": false,
            "caption": "Close",
            "name": "ButtonClose",
            "empty": false,
            "msg": "fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOff')",
            "buttonIcon": 1027,
            "favourite": false,
            "main": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "elements": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "lua": true,
            "waitForResponse": false,
            "caption": "Toggle",
            "name": "ButtonToggle",
            "empty": false,
            "msg": "local sensor = fibaro:getValue ('540', 'value');\n\nif sensor ~= '0'\nthen   \n  fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOff')\nelse  \n  fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOn')\nend",
            "buttonIcon": 1027,
            "favourite": false,
            "main": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions": {
    "pressButton": 1,
    "setSlider": 2,
    "setProperty": 2
  }
}
```

**rows** is an array of visual elements.  Here there are 3 rows

- A label with caption='Status' and name 'LabelStatus'
- Two buttons with captions of 'Open' and 'Close'
- One button with a caption 'Toggle'

The field called `msg` is the actual lua code for that element. Lines are separated with `\n`.  The formatted lua for say element 4 is

```lua
local sensor = fibaro:getValue ('540', 'value');

if sensor ~= '0'
then   
  fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOff')
else  
  fibaro:call ('214', 'turnOn')
end
```

The field called `mainLoop` is the main loop's lua code.  Other fields are obvious.